# How to change the projection of a UTM-georeferenced raster in Quantum?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have a project file in Quantum which contains some shapefiles and rasters that are properly georeferenced. However, I have started using GeoTiffs which are in UTM - WGS84 that don't seem to be projecting properly.

When I import the GeoTiffs, Quantum reads their X,Y (Eastings, Northings) coordinates like they were lat,lon. How can I convert these X,Y values into lat,lon coordinates? I have set all the layers in the project file to the same coordinate system and I have also enabled on the fly CRS transofrmation to no avail.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Don't change the layer CRS in properties. Please read this first http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/23025/187

Answer (score 2):

1) Plugins > Manage Plugins. Enable GdalTools
[image]

2) Then:
[image]

3) Enter the source and destination SRS and the other parameters. That's it.